# ValueError: Unknown fields ['image']

Tags: dask, dask-kubernetes

I am trying to deploy Dask Gateway integrated with JupyterHub which is the reason I decided to give DaskHub Chart a try.
After following the instructions on https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/kubernetes-helm.html#helm-install-dask-for-mulitple-users. The JH is working fine but When I try to create a new Dask cluster via the UI or through:

```
[from dask_gateway import GatewayCluster
cluster = GatewayCluster()][2]
```

### I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-36809e239298> in <module>
      1 from dask_gateway import GatewayCluster
----> 2 cluster = GatewayCluster()
      3 

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask_gateway/client.py in __init__(self, address, proxy_address, public_address, auth, cluster_options, shutdown_on_close, asynchronous, loop, **kwargs)
    816             shutdown_on_close=shutdown_on_close,
    817             asynchronous=asynchronous,
--> 818             loop=loop,
    819         )
    820 

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask_gateway/client.py in _init_internal(self, address, proxy_address, public_address, auth, cluster_options, cluster_kwargs, shutdown_on_close, asynchronous, loop, name)
    912             self.status = "starting"
    913         if not self.asynchronous:
--> 914             self.gateway.sync(self._start_internal)
    915 
    916     @property

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask_gateway/client.py in sync(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    337             )
    338             try:
--> 339                 return future.result()
    340             except BaseException:
    341                 future.cancel()

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    433                 raise CancelledError()
    434             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 435                 return self.__get_result()
    436             else:
    437                 raise TimeoutError()

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask_gateway/client.py in _start_internal(self)
    926             self._start_task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._start_async())
    927         try:
--> 928             await self._start_task
    929         except BaseException:
    930             # On exception, cleanup

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask_gateway/client.py in _start_async(self)
    940             self.status = "starting"
    941             self.name = await self.gateway._submit(
--> 942                 cluster_options=self._cluster_options, **self._cluster_kwargs
    943             )
    944         # Connect to cluster

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask_gateway/client.py in _submit(self, cluster_options, **kwargs)
    529             options = self._config_cluster_options()
    530             options.update(kwargs)
--> 531         resp = await self._request("POST", url, json={"cluster_options": options})
    532         data = await resp.json()
    533         return data["name"]

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask_gateway/client.py in _request(self, method, url, json)
    407 
    408             if resp.status in {404, 422}:
--> 409                 raise ValueError(msg)
    410             elif resp.status == 409:
    411                 raise GatewayClusterError(msg)

ValueError: Unknown fields ['image']
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.